# Change resource strings post compilation

Tags: silverlight, localization

I have a Silverlight application that uses resource files to be able to change the language in use at run-time. So at the moment there are 2 .resx files but in the future we may want to add languages or update incorrect values. However this seems to be compiled into the application and thus cannot be changed at run-time.

Is there a way to be able to update what is used by the application without re-compiling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localizable resources will be embedded in satellite assemblies, to support a new language you simply have to add that assemblies in the proper folder.

Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838238(v=vs.95).aspx